# sha-512 not working properly on IOS Simulator

Tags: ios

I am implementing mobile app  sha-512 function that will run on IOS, this function is working fine on all browsers including Safari.

I am testing my application using IOS Simulator.

My application is calling sha-512 function three times from one page/click. The problem is that, at first call sha-512 function produces right result, but at second and third call it produces wrong result.

thanks in advance

Comment: paste your code of what you have tried, I am also using SHA-512, but have never faced such issue

Answer (score 0):

This is my code

```
//Creating Hash Value
NSString *hashkey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data"];
// PHP uses ASCII encoding, not UTF
NSLog(@"hashkey : %@",hashkey);
const char *s = [hashkey cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSData *keyData = [NSData dataWithBytes:s length:strlen(s)];

// This is the destination SHA512_Final
uint8_t digest[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};
// This one function does an unkeyed SHA1 hash of your hash data
CC_SHA512(keyData.bytes, keyData.length, digest);

// Now convert to NSData structure to make it usable again
NSData *out = [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
// description converts to hex but puts <> around it and spaces every 4 bytes
NSString *hash = [out description];
hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: i am implementing sha512 function in javascript using this link: http://jssha.sourceforge.net/ kindly help me using javascript

Comment: @vikaskumar Why are you using javascript for this, Apple already has inbuilt library for SHA 512

Comment: i am developing web application + mobile web application, and using sha512 function for password validation, also doing some XOR operation over hashed values(binary) for next level of authentication. this function must produce same output for web application and mobile web application...

Comment: Its highly risky to use javascript for iPhone application, as if user turns off Javascript from settings, your code will not work. Also, paste your javascript code

Comment: i have copied the same code from http://jssha.sourceforge.net/ its working on all browsers, working only once on IOS Sumulator also, but at next call produces wrong output..